# Using Lookup or Dictionary to represent a hand of cards in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, lookup

> I apologize if there is a similar question already out there.  There
>   are several questions about scoring hands but I don't need that.
>
> The project I am working on takes in 10 cards and needs to report the
>   best possible 5-card hand found ("straight", "high card", "flush"
>   etc.).  Luckily what the actual hand of cards is is irrelevant, I just
>   need a name.
>
> I've already parsed and sorted all the cards out and have the tests
>   for all the possible hands laid out.  All I need now is a convenient
>   way to store the hands.  My mad method is as follows, in pseudocode
>   terms:
>
> **I want to have a dynamic list horizontally that I can populate with the NUMBER values of the cards, in order from highest to lowest.  For
>   example, "Q J T 7 4 2 1".  T is 10.  Duplicates of values will be
>   ignored.  Next, I want each of those values to have, underneath, a
>   list of the suits of each value that exist in the deck.  For example,
>   J will have a sub-list with the values "D H" to represent that I have
>   a Jack of Diamonds and a Jack of Hearts.**
>
> I believe this to be the most elegant way to deal with these cards,
>   since most poker hands deal with only values and this way I don't have
>   to worry about cards of the same value in a row for say the straight
>   test.  Then the two tests that *do* deal with suit can easily be
>   tested for by referring to the values under the keys.
>
> Take a deep breath, almost there.
>
> So an instance of Lookup appears to be perfect!  It has the exact "one
>   key to multiple values" structure that I want.  However, it doesn't
>   allow me to add the suits as I come to them.  I have to add them all
>   at once or not at all since the lists are immutable after entry.
>
> So I either
>
> 1. have to find all the suits at once before I even make the Lookup
> 2. Somehow add values to the Lookup lists or
> 3. Use something else.
>
> Any ideas on any of these?

### UPDATE

**TL;DR SPARKNOTES VERSION:  How can I add more values to the keys inside of a Lookup?**

**IMOPRTANT NOTE:**The output of this program should be a string containing the name of the highest hand possible, for example "four of a kind", "two pair" or "high card."

I found one solution (which I unfortunately lost the link to and can't find again) where they suggested re-creating the entire Lookup with the new list.  It may just be me but I find that solution to be very... ugly...  Anyway several other solutions I have explored or tested are to:

---

### METHOD 1

Roll through and populate another array with the suits associated with each value.  Basically (in actual pseudocode this time >_>):

1. Create an array of ArrayLists (array 1)
2. Iterate through a sorted string array of "cards" (array 2)
3. For each card:
4. Take the char at string index [1] (representing the suit) and add into the ArrayList in array 1 at the index number extracted from string index [0].

This way I have the list of values with associated suits that I wanted.  And the list of suits is the minimal size to boot, making iteration through that easier later.  With some extra steps I can even make the umbrella array an ArrayList and populate it with the card values in order so there are no gaps and no duplicate numbers.  This will leave me with a jagged array of what I want.  To be clear, this is not a homework assignment.  However, it IS from a coding class project my roommate completed in the past which is why I have the constrictions and requirements I have.  Someone else I asked told me SE gets plagued by these kinds of homework questions around this time, so I understand your skepticism.  This is a personal project because I want to learn C# (all I know is Java right now, and I like the sound of parameter pointer passing in C# methods, which Java does not do).

If it WERE for a grade I would end there because it works.  But I don't really like arraylists of arraylists, they seem messy to me.  So I want to know if there is another method.

---

### METHOD 2

I also considered simply dealing with duplicates that inevitably appear.  For example, here is my test for a straight:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < i + 4; j++)
            {
                int secondCard = getValue(cardsArray[j + 1]);
                int firstCard = getValue(cardsArray[j]);
                if (secondCard == firstCard)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (secondCard == (firstCard + 1))
                {
                    counter++;
                    if (counter == 4)
                    {
                        isStraight = true;
                        return "straight";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This code does not work.  It needs some tweaks somewhere or other to work completely but I want to analyze if it is worth it before I try to fix it.  It DOES accurately test for a straight, though.  Also a couple notes: firstCard and secondCard are there for readability and debug purposes, and isStraight is there so that I don't reinvent the wheel later when I test for a straight flush.

This nested loop will iterate through all the cards up till the 5th card (since you can't have a straight out of ten sorted cards with less than 5 cards) and then check the next five cards as you would expect.  If during this iteration I encounter a duplicate entry it means that it's the same card of another suit and I simply "break".  What SHOULD happen as a result of this one statement is that now we have incremented our second iteration by one to check the next card instead of the current one.  The count of in-order cards that we have will stay the same so that a list like " 1D 2D 3S 3H 4D 5C"  will skip over the second 3 when finding the straight.  Despite the break I was actually quite pleased with the elegance of this solution, whether I had a right to be or not.

It all goes back to the flaws of using a simple array of strings ("cards"), which is what my code is tailored to right now.  And I hate fixing issues, I'd rather avoid them.  Maybe I'm being unnecessarily picky but I'm learning along the way.

---

### METHOD 3

My consideration of the weaknesses of an array of strings lead me to Dictionaries, which looked attractive.  It can easily be made to hold my values in order, and easy to find if I have a certain suit for a key (TryGet), all in a neat, tailor-made package.  Creating multiple array lists and doing things like "(find index of my value);  array1[index].Add(value)" would be replaced by "Dictionary.Add(value, suit)".  But I can only add a suit to a key at the point of creation.  I couldn't make a "2" key and add "S" and then when I find out the next card is a "2D" add a D under the "2" key.  Dictionary just doesn't support that, or even adding multiple values at all.  I can make a dictionary of lists, but I still can't edit the list since Dictionaries are mostly query data structures.  Lookups support multiple values per key but still cannot be changed after the initial "Add()".  Again I could "re-create" the entire lookup or dictionary to add a suit and keep everything in order.  But to me that seems like rebuilding the whole bridge because this one cable is too long and I don't have an industrial able cutter.  It's a problem that SHOULD have an easier solution, like maybe go and GET some cutters (import a class maybe?).

---

### CONCLUSION

Since you suggest that my needs are no different than what a hand scoring system could deliver leads me to another question:

Are hand scores directly tied to certain hands?  Like I mentioned earlier the result I want is "The best hand you can make is a full house" not "This player has the highest hand."  So can I calculate the highest scoring hand and extrapolate a "full house" from that score?  If so then I guess this is all unnecessary code, but I would kind of like to solve this anyway in that case.

As I wrote this edit it dawned on me that this is basically a vanity issue.  I don't "like" the solution I have.  I also don't want to use the accepted solution (table lookup) because that is not a coding project that is a copypaste project.  I would greatly appreciate any input.

Comment: 1) Your pseudocode isn't; it's another list of demands. 2) What have you actually tried?

Comment: From what I remember of the hand scoring methods I've seen, I don't see anything in your requirements that *isn't* covered by them, or slight modifications thereof. And I don't see how your proposed lookup method can be faster or take less space. Perhaps if you explain your idea a little more clearly along with proposed data structures and some real pseudocode. And their method of storing the hands (a 64-bit number, with the low 13 bits of each 16 used to indicate that the card exists in the hand).

Comment: These points are fair enough.  I purposely left any code and a lot of details out in the interest of simplicity.  Lemme update the original with some more work and a tl;dr.

Comment: Alright I did a major overhaul.  If you two would be kind enough to give it another read I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this the simplest way possible. First, say you have an array of 10 strings, each of which is the name of a card. Like "Four of Hearts" and "Queen of Spades". That's really inconvenient to work with. So the first thing we do is convert those strings to numbers to represent each card. A very convenient way to do it is to use numbers 0-12 for hearts, 13-25 for diamonds, etc. So you have code (possibly a lookup table) that converts names to numbers:

```
Ace of Hearts = 0
Two of Hearts = 1
Three of Hearts = 2
...
Queen of Hearts = 11
King of Hearts = 12
Ace of Diamonds = 13
...
...
Ace of Clubs = 26
...
...
Kind of Spades = 51
```

So you have an array of numbers that represents the 10 cards. Call it `cardsArray`:

```
int[] cardsArray = new int[10];
// here, fill the cards array from the input
```

It's easy to check for flushes if you sort by suit and value. Remember, there are only 10 cards, so sorting isn't going to take a huge amount of time. The sort is really easy:

```
int[] sortedBySuit = 
    cardsArray
    .OrderBy(x => x/13)  // sorts by suit
    .ThenByDescending(x => x % 13) // then by value, descending
    .ToArray();
```

You can then go sequentially through the array and determine if you have a flush, straight flush, and what the high card in the flush (if any) is.

You have to save that information, because four-of-a-kind beats a flush, for example. So you need to check that, too.

Next, sort by value:

```
int[] sortedByValue =
    cardsArray
    .OrderByDescending(x => x % 13)
    .ToArray();
```

Now you can go sequentially through that list to determine high card, pairs, three of a kind, four of a kind, or straights. As you find each type of hand, you save that hand information ("king high straight" or "three tens", along with the hand's value [1 for high card, 2 for pair, straight, flush, full house, etc. in the proper order]) to a list.

Then you just pick the hand with the highest value from those that you found.

That's definitely not the *fastest* way to do things, but it's simple, uses very little memory, and is fast enough for a prototype. It's certainly simpler than using a dictionary or array of arrays, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, I didn't read your novel.

> TL;DR SPARKNOTES VERSION: How can I add more values to the keys inside of a Lookup?

Usually, when I need a "dictionary" with a key that has multiple values, I use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`.  You could use LINQ to Objects to select all the values.  For example:

```
    static void StackOverflowExample()
    {
        var cardList = new List<KeyValuePair<string,int>> ()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Club", 8),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Spade", 9),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Heart", 10)
        };

        var results = cardList.Where(p => p.Key == "Heart");
    }
```

var results is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,int>>`.  Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: So it's basically a "custom-built" dictionary.  I like it.  I need to be able to

Comment: ignore the last few words.  What does "LINQ to Objects" mean?

Comment: [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) - basically a way to query collections (such as lists) in C#.